# Updating value in table via controller method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Ok so I'm basicalling trying to create a reddit style page in Ruby on rails where users can submit links and then upvote/downvote them. I generated a scaffolding for the links which basically works like the blog tutorial and then custom wrote a migration to add a vote_count:integer column to the links table. I then went into the controller an added methods of upvote (which increments links.vote_count) and downvote (which decrements links.vote_count) and on the index.erb.html page where it displays all the link I want to creak a "link_to" button that calls those methods. The way I have things now though I get the error: Couldn't find Link without an ID.

Relevant part of links_controller.rb

```
class LinksController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_link, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /links
  # GET /links.json
  def index
    @links = Link.all
  end

  def upvote
    @link = Link.find(params[:id])
    @link.vote_count += 1
  end

  def downvote
    @link = Link.find(params[:id])
    @link.vote_count -= 1
  end
```

relevant part of index.html.erb

```
<tbody>
    <% @links.each do |link| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= link.vote_count %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Up', upvote_links_path(link) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Down', downvote_links_path(link) %></td>
        <td><%= link.title %></td>
        <td><%= link.url %></td>
        <td><%= link.user_id %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', link %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_link_path(link) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', link, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

routes.rb

```
resources :links do
    collection do
      get :upvote
      get :downvote
    end
  end
```

Is there an easier way to update this table value or what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your routes. Since upvote and downvote methods are going to act on a link you need to use member instead of collection.

```
resources :links do
  member do
    get :upvote
    get :downvote
  end
end
```

Comment: Since I'm relatively new to rails could you explain the difference between member and collection?

Comment: Sure. Think of collection as actions you would like to do all the links. For example, if you wanted to add a search functionality. You would do this: `collection do; get :search; end`. This way you would get a url like this: `/links/search`. You want to use member if you want to reference a specific link. All the action inside of member, get the ID passed in. So for your case, you url would be `/links/ID/upvote`. Then you can reference which link needs to be upvoted.

Comment: That makes sense. I've changed routes to member but am still getting the error "undefined method on upvote_links_path". To fix this I adjusted to the appropriate upvote_link_path (no s) since thats what changing to member did but now I get the error that there's no defined template for the page /links/upvote but I don't want it to redirect to a page I just want it to call the action upvote and stay on the present page. What do I need to do next?